# Add an interactive button to switch which variable is mapped to fill in ggplotly in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

Using the same set of data, I have produced two different tile plots as shown below:

DATA:

```
> dput(coupler.graph)
structure(list(Category = c("HBC", "TC", "BSC", "GSC", "GSC", 
"SSC", "SSC", "GSC", "GSC", "SSC", "SSC", "SSC", "HBC", "TC", 
"BSC", "BSC", "GSC", "GSC", "SSC", "HBC", "HBC", "TC", "TC", 
"BSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "TC", "BSC", "BSC", 
"GSC", "GSC"), `Bar Size` = c("No. 5", "No. 5", "No. 5", "No. 5", 
"No. 5", "No. 6", "No. 6", "No. 6", "No. 6", "No. 8", "No. 8", 
"No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", 
"No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", 
"No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 11", "No. 11", "No. 18", "No. 18", "No. 18", 
"No. 18", "No. 18"), `No. Bars` = c(3, 9, 3, 6, 6, 85, 85, 7, 
7, 90, 90, 90, 7, 9, 6, 6, 21, 21, 9, 22, 22, 27, 27, 13, 25, 
25, 25, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), Failure = c("Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", 
"Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", 
"Bar fracture", "Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure", 
"Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", 
"Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", 
"Coupler failure", "Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure", 
"Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", 
"Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure", "Coupler failure", 
"Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure"
), x = c("1-3", "7-9", "1-3", "5-7", "5-7", "30-90", "30-90", 
"5-7", "5-7", "30-90", "30-90", "30-90", "5-7", "7-9", "5-7", 
"5-7", "20-30", "20-30", "7-9", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", 
"11-15", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "7-9", "7-9", "3-5", "3-5", 
"3-5", "3-5", "3-5")), row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The first plot is showing the number of specimens as:

```
labels1 <- factor(c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9",
            "9-11", "11-15",  "15-20","20-90"), levels = 
              c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9",
            "9-11", "11-15",  "15-20","20-30","30-90"))
values1 <- c("white", "#ffffd9", "#edf8b1", "#c7e9b4", "#7fcdbb",
            "#41b6c4", "#1d91c0",  "#225ea8", "#253494","#081d58")

bar_list = c("No. 5", "No. 6",  "No. 8",  "No. 10", "No. 11", "No. 14", "No. 18")

plot1 <- ggplot(coupler.graph) + aes(x = Category, y = fct_inorder(`Bar Size`), fill = factor(x, 
                                    levels = c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9",
                                               "9-11", "11-15",  "15-20","20-30", "30-90"))) +
 geom_tile(width=0.9, height=0.9) + theme_classic() + scale_fill_manual(labels = factor(labels1), values = values1) +
 labs(x = "Splicer Type", y = "Bar Size") + scale_y_discrete(limits = bar_list) +
 theme(plot.title = element_blank(), axis.text =  element_text(color = "black", size = 12), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
       axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2), axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2),
       axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(0,40,0,0)), 
       axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(35,0,0,0)),
       legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12)) 

ggplotly(
  p = ggplot2::last_plot(),
  width = NULL,
  height = NULL,
  tooltip = c("Category", "Failure"),
  dynamicTicks = FALSE,
  layerData = 1,
  originalData = TRUE,) %>% add_annotations( text="Number of\nSpecimens", xref="paper", yref="paper",
                  x=1.1, xanchor="left", y=0.8, yanchor="bottom", font = list(size = 18),
                  legendtitle=TRUE, showarrow=FALSE ) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = list(text = "Bar Size", standoff = 30L)),
             xaxis = list(title = list(text = "Bar Size",standoff = 30L)),
             legend = list(orientation = "v", x = 1.1, y = 0.13))
```

And the resulted plot is :

[image]

The second plot is showing the failure type:

```
values2 <-  c("Bar fracture" = "red", "Bar pullout" = "blue", "Coupler failure" = "yellow")

plot2 <- ggplot(coupler.graph) + aes(x = Category, y = fct_inorder(`Bar Size`), fill = Failure) +
 geom_tile(width=0.9, height=0.9) + theme_classic() + scale_fill_manual(values = values2) +
 labs(x = "Splicer Type", y = "Bar Size") + scale_y_discrete(limits = bar_list) +
 theme(plot.title = element_blank(), axis.text =  element_text(color = "black", size = 12), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
       axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2), axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2),
       axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(0,40,0,0)), 
       axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(35,0,0,0)),
       legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12)) 

ggplotly(
  p = ggplot2::last_plot(),
  width = NULL,
  height = NULL,
  tooltip = c("Category", "Failure"),
  dynamicTicks = FALSE,
  layerData = 1,
  originalData = TRUE,) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = list(text = "Bar Size", standoff = 30L)),
             xaxis = list(title = list(text = "Bar Size",standoff = 30L)),
             legend = list(orientation = "v", x = 1.1, y = 0.13))
```

And the resulted plot is shown:

[image]

I would like to add a button to the HTML output such as [the example here](https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/) does for different chart types, but switching between these two plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a static html-file, you could use some custom js and html to do what you wish for.
To do this you'll first need a little helper-function which you can just add to your markdown-file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function showSolution(){
        first=document.getElementById('first')
        second=document.getElementById('second')
        if(first.style.visibility=='visible'){
            first.style.visibility='hidden';
            first.style.display='none';
            second.style.visibility="visible";
            second.style.display='block';
        }else{
            first.style.visibility="visible";
            first.style.display='block';
            second.style.visibility='hidden';
            second.style.display='none';
        }
    }

    -->
```

Then you'll need a button that uses the helper-function:

```
<input type='button' value='Change plot' onclick='showSolution();'/>
```

And to finnish up, you'll only need to wrap your graphics-creating chunks into some div-tags:

````
<div id='first' style='visibility:visible;display:block'>
```{r}
labels1 <- factor(c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9",
            "9-11", "11-15",  "15-20","20-90"), levels = 
              c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9",
            "9-11", "11-15",  "15-20","20-30","30-90"))
values1 <- c("white", "#ffffd9", "#edf8b1", "#c7e9b4", "#7fcdbb",
            "#41b6c4", "#1d91c0",  "#225ea8", "#253494","#081d58")

bar_list = c("No. 5", "No. 6",  "No. 8",  "No. 10", "No. 11", "No. 14", "No. 18")

plot1 <- ggplot(coupler.graph) + aes(x = Category, y = fct_inorder(`Bar Size`), fill = factor(x, 
                                    levels = c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9",
                                               "9-11", "11-15",  "15-20","20-30", "30-90"))) +
 geom_tile(width=0.9, height=0.9) + theme_classic() + scale_fill_manual(labels = factor(labels1), values = values1) +
 labs(x = "Splicer Type", y = "Bar Size") + scale_y_discrete(limits = bar_list) +
 theme(plot.title = element_blank(), axis.text =  element_text(color = "black", size = 12), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
       axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2), axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2),
       axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(0,40,0,0)), 
       axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(35,0,0,0)),
       legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12)) 

ggplotly(
  p = ggplot2::last_plot(),
  width = NULL,
  height = NULL,
  tooltip = c("Category", "Failure"),
  dynamicTicks = FALSE,
  layerData = 1,
  originalData = TRUE,) %>% add_annotations( text="Number of\nSpecimens", xref="paper", yref="paper",
                  x=1.1, xanchor="left", y=0.8, yanchor="bottom", font = list(size = 18),
                  legendtitle=TRUE, showarrow=FALSE ) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = list(text = "Bar Size", standoff = 30L)),
             xaxis = list(title = list(text = "Bar Size",standoff = 30L)),
             legend = list(orientation = "v", x = 1.1, y = 0.13))
```

</div>


<div id='second' style='visibility:hidden;display:none'>
```{r}
values2 <-  c("Bar fracture" = "red", "Bar pullout" = "blue", "Coupler failure" = "yellow")

plot2 <- ggplot(coupler.graph) + aes(x = Category, y = fct_inorder(`Bar Size`), fill = Failure) +
 geom_tile(width=0.9, height=0.9) + theme_classic() + scale_fill_manual(values = values2) +
 labs(x = "Splicer Type", y = "Bar Size") + scale_y_discrete(limits = bar_list) +
 theme(plot.title = element_blank(), axis.text =  element_text(color = "black", size = 12), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
       axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2), axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2),
       axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(0,40,0,0)), 
       axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(35,0,0,0)),
       legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12)) 

ggplotly(
  p = ggplot2::last_plot(),
  width = NULL,
  height = NULL,
  tooltip = c("Category", "Failure"),
  dynamicTicks = FALSE,
  layerData = 1,
  originalData = TRUE,) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = list(text = "Bar Size", standoff = 30L)),
             xaxis = list(title = list(text = "Bar Size",standoff = 30L)),
             legend = list(orientation = "v", x = 1.1, y = 0.13))
```
</div>
````

This will result in an html like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case you are willing to consider using [{shiny}](https://rstudio.com/products/shiny/), here is an approach to select which plot to display based on button clicks.

## Visual

[image]

## Code

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(forcats)



# Load data
coupler.graph <- structure(list(Category = c(
  "HBC", "TC", "BSC", "GSC", "GSC",
  "SSC", "SSC", "GSC", "GSC", "SSC", "SSC", "SSC", "HBC", "TC",
  "BSC", "BSC", "GSC", "GSC", "SSC", "HBC", "HBC", "TC", "TC",
  "BSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "TC", "BSC", "BSC",
  "GSC", "GSC"
), `Bar Size` = c(
  "No. 5", "No. 5", "No. 5", "No. 5",
  "No. 5", "No. 6", "No. 6", "No. 6", "No. 6", "No. 8", "No. 8",
  "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8",
  "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10",
  "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 11", "No. 11", "No. 18", "No. 18", "No. 18",
  "No. 18", "No. 18"
), `No. Bars` = c(
  3, 9, 3, 6, 6, 85, 85, 7,
  7, 90, 90, 90, 7, 9, 6, 6, 21, 21, 9, 22, 22, 27, 27, 13, 25,
  25, 25, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
), Failure = c(
  "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture",
  "Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Bar pullout",
  "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure",
  "Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture",
  "Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar pullout",
  "Coupler failure", "Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure",
  "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", "Bar fracture",
  "Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure", "Coupler failure",
  "Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure"
), x = c(
  "1-3", "7-9", "1-3", "5-7", "5-7", "30-90", "30-90",
  "5-7", "5-7", "30-90", "30-90", "30-90", "5-7", "7-9", "5-7",
  "5-7", "20-30", "20-30", "7-9", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30",
  "11-15", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "7-9", "7-9", "3-5", "3-5",
  "3-5", "3-5", "3-5"
)), row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
))



# make plot 1
labels1 <- factor(
  c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9", "9-11", "11-15", "15-20", "20-90"),
  levels = c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9", "9-11", "11-15", "15-20", "20-30", "30-90")
)

values1 <- c(
  "white", "#ffffd9", "#edf8b1", "#c7e9b4", "#7fcdbb",
  "#41b6c4", "#1d91c0", "#225ea8", "#253494", "#081d58"
)

bar_list <- c("No. 5", "No. 6", "No. 8", "No. 10", "No. 11", "No. 14", "No. 18")

ggplot1 <- ggplot(
  coupler.graph,
  aes(
    x = Category,
    y = fct_inorder(`Bar Size`),
    fill = factor(x, levels = c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9", "9-11", "11-15", "15-20", "20-30", "30-90"))
  )
) +
  geom_tile(width = 0.9, height = 0.9) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = factor(labels1), values = values1) +
  labs(x = "Splicer Type", y = "Bar Size") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = bar_list) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_blank(), axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2), axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(0, 40, 0, 0)),
    axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(35, 0, 0, 0)),
    legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12)
  )

ggplotly1 <- ggplotly(
  p = ggplot1,
  width = NULL,
  height = NULL,
  tooltip = c("Category", "Failure"),
  dynamicTicks = FALSE,
  layerData = 1,
  originalData = TRUE,
) %>%
  add_annotations(
    text = "Number of\nSpecimens", xref = "paper", yref = "paper",
    x = 1.1, xanchor = "left", y = 0.8, yanchor = "bottom", font = list(size = 18),
    legendtitle = TRUE, showarrow = FALSE
  ) %>%
  layout(
    yaxis = list(title = list(text = "Bar Size", standoff = 30L)),
    xaxis = list(title = list(text = "Bar Size", standoff = 30L)),
    legend = list(orientation = "v", x = 1.1, y = 0.13)
  )



# make plot 2
values2 <- c("Bar fracture" = "red", "Bar pullout" = "blue", "Coupler failure" = "yellow")

ggplot2 <- ggplot(coupler.graph) +
  aes(x = Category, y = fct_inorder(`Bar Size`), fill = Failure) +
  geom_tile(width = 0.9, height = 0.9) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = values2) +
  labs(x = "Splicer Type", y = "Bar Size") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = bar_list) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_blank(), axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2), axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(0, 40, 0, 0)),
    axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(35, 0, 0, 0)),
    legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12)
  )

ggplotly2 <- ggplotly(
  p = ggplot2,
  width = NULL,
  height = NULL,
  tooltip = c("Category", "Failure"),
  dynamicTicks = FALSE,
  layerData = 1,
  originalData = TRUE,
) %>%
  layout(
    yaxis = list(title = list(text = "Bar Size", standoff = 30L)),
    xaxis = list(title = list(text = "Bar Size", standoff = 30L)),
    legend = list(orientation = "v", x = 1.1, y = 0.13)
  )



ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Swap Plotlies"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            flowLayout(
                actionButton("show_plot_1", "Show Plot 1"),
                actionButton("show_plot_2", "Show Plot 2")
            )
        ),
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("plot_hole")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$show_plot_1, { 
        output$plot_hole <- renderUI({ plotlyOutput("plot_1") })
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$show_plot_2, { 
        output$plot_hole <- renderUI({ plotlyOutput("plot_2") })
    })
    
    output$plot_1 <- renderPlotly({ ggplotly1 })
    
    output$plot_2 <- renderPlotly({ ggplotly2 })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```